# Error while using static_cast operator on unrelated types

Tags: c++, casting

I was working on a recent task on a coding platform and came across a problem I couldn't solve.
Basically, I was supposed to use "static_cast Operator" between unrelated types. And at a point I had to use the conversion "Container==>int". I have tried doing it multiple ways but still wind up with some error. PS- I CAN ONLY EDIT LINE-1, LINE-2 and LINE-3.

CASE 1: Programtest.cpp:14:14: error: expected type-specifier operator Container::Container(){ // LINE-3

```
Container(int k) : i(k) { } // LINE-1

operator int(){ // LINE-2
    return arr[--i];
}

operator Container::Container(){ // LINE-3
```

CASE 2: Programtest.cpp: In member function Container::operator Container(): test.cpp:16:29: error: k was not declared in this scope for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){

```
Container(int k) : i(k) { } // LINE-1

operator int(){ // LINE-2
    return arr[--i];
}

operator Container(){ // LINE-3
```

Here is the full program code for reference.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Container {
    int i;
    int *arr;
public:
    Container(int k) : i(k) { } // LINE-1

    operator int(){ // LINE-2
        return arr[--i];
    }
    
    operator Container(){ // LINE-3
 int t;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            cin >> t;
            this->arr[j] = t;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    int k;
    cin >> k;

    Container c(k);
    c = k;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << static_cast<int>(c) << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with R or Rcpp so I will remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

> PS- I CAN ONLY EDIT LINE-1, LINE-2 and LINE-3.

There is no way to fix this program by editing only those lines. The definition of `operator Container` is broken. It uses a variable that hasn't been defined.

This broken function is never called in the program, so simple solution would be to remove it entirely. In fact because it is the identity conversion operator, it is not even possible to call the function. It is entirely useless.

If you could modify one other line, then it could be compiled:

Replace

> ```
>  operator Container(){ // LINE-3
> ```

with:

```
/*
```

Also, add

```
*/
```

after the definition of `operator Container`. This is the extra line that must be modified.

However, although this makes the program compile, it is still broken. `arr` is never initialised, and the program indirects through it which results in undefined behaviour. This can be fixed by initialising `arr` to point to an array of sufficient length

> ```
> Container(int k) : i(k) { } // LINE-1
> ```

with

```
Container(int k) : i(k), arr(new int[k]()) { }
```

However, this dynamic array will leak in the example program. The design of the class is bad; I would not recommend writing anything like this for a real program.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Container {
    int i;
    int *arr;
    public:
    Container(int k) : i(k), arr(new int[k]()) { } // LINE-1

    operator int() { // LINE-2
        return arr[--i];
    }

    Container& operator=(int &k)  { // LINE-3
   int t; 
    k= this->i;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            cin >> t;
            this->arr[j] = t;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    int k;
    cin >> k;

    Container c(k);
    c = k;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        cout << static_cast<int>(c) << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please could you add some explanations?